# How to give authorities for users with Java Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I try to get some users from db and give them authorities. Those are my user class fields.

```
private String  username;
private String  email;
private String  password;
private String  role;
```

I want give authorities by string role.
I tried this:

```
@Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
          .withUser("user1").password(passwordEncoder().encode("user1Pass"))
          .authorities("ROLE_USER");
}
```

but I don't know how to get the users from db and use them in configureGlobal method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `JdbcUserDetailsManager` to load users from DB

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
           .dataSource({datasource})
           .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password,1 "+ "from xxx " + "where username = ?")
           .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role "+ "from xxx " + "where username = ?")
}
```

The 1 in the usersByUsernameQuery means enabled.

Comment: I think there is typo... `{datasource}` should have been `datasource`

Answer (score 3):

Approach 1:

You can set the dataSource and pass the queries to read users and authorities like below:

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource; //autowire the data source

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, 1 as enabled from user where username=?") 
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, authority from user_authority where username=?"); //check the for columns.
    }
```

In this case table looks like this

**user** table:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  email VARCHAR(50),
  password VARCHAR(500),
  activated BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
  activationkey VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  resetpasswordkey VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

**user_authority** table:

```
CREATE TABLE user_authority (
    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    authority VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES user (username),
    FOREIGN KEY (authority) REFERENCES authority (name),
    UNIQUE INDEX user_authority_idx_1 (username, authority)
);
```

Approach 2:

You can implement user details service for any custom implementation if required, the below is just an **example** user name is not case sensitive:

```
@Component("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsService implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDetailsService.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String login) {

        log.debug("Authenticating {}", login);
        String lowercaseLogin = login.toLowerCase();

        User userFromDatabase = userRepository.findByUsernameCaseInsensitive(lowercaseLogin);


        if (userFromDatabase == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " was not found in the database");
        } else if (!userFromDatabase.isActivated()) {
            throw new UserNotActivatedException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " is not activated");
        }

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Authority authority : userFromDatabase.getAuthorities()) {
            GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getName());
            grantedAuthorities.add(grantedAuthority);
        }

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(userFromDatabase.getUsername(), userFromDatabase.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);

    }

}
```

and security config:

```
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new StandardPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

    }
```

Hope it helps